# Linking to GWT instance method from JSNI does not automatically bind "this"

Tags: gwt, jsni

I am going to file this as a bug report, but I wanted to check if someone here can see something wrong with what I am doing.

When you expose an instance method from a GWT class through JSNI, `this` works as expected in JavaScript. Since we are cross compiling Java, I would instead expect `this` to be bound to the instance automatically. For example:

```
package com.test;
class Foo {

    public void instanceFunction() {
        this.otherFunction() // will cause an error when called from JSNI!
    }

    public void otherFunction() {
        // does some stuff
    }

    public native JavaScriptObject getInstanceFunction() /*-{
        return this.@com.test.Foo::instanceFunction();
    }-*/;

}
```

Currently the workaround is to bind the function yourself (not very portable):

```
    public native JavaScriptObject getInstanceFunction() /*-{
        return this.@com.test.Foo::instanceFunction().bind(this);
    }-*/;
```

This can also be seen as preference, some may prefer that the functions remain unbound. I would say the current functionality is unintuitave and unnecessary. I cannot imagine a use case for having an unbound `this` directly in Java code. Also, some browsers do not implement `bind(1)`, so my workaround is not robust.

Comment: And so, what's your question?

Comment: I think the functionality of the compiler should be changed. My question is asking if someone knows of a better way, or a reason to keep the compiler how it is.

Comment: Reason for not changing the compiler: backwards compatibility. Though feel free to ask the enhancement on code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/entry, who knows what the _compiler guys_ think…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a portable `bind`, it's as easy as:

```
var that = this;
return $entry(function() {
   return that.@com.test.Foo::instanceFunction()();
});
```